# How to create a login portlet in liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I need to create a login portlet and based on the loggedin user i need to change the result page.Means if the loggedin user is admin then i need to show all the portlets,and if the loggedin user is user then i need to show only the user information.Any one has an idea on this.Providing any samle will be appreciated.Thank You.My required technologies are:liferay6.1,spring,jsp,jquery

Comment: cant you just add the portlets and give them the correct view right?
maybe i dont understand your question correctly...
you could check the user after login and redirect to a page based on what kind of user is logging in

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying.Can you be bit clear.I am very new to liferay.Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: what do you need?
do you want to show different portlets for a user after login
or do you want the two user types to come to a completely different page after login?

Comment: I want to show different portlets for a use after login.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a login hook, and handle the redirect after a successful login.

You can start with a [hook tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-action)

However, you can't manage which portlets are going to be accessible or not, this way. There is a permissions mechanism to do that. You can just use the redirection to prompt them to different pages, hosting the portlets that are accessible to the logged user.